# Best way to optimize multiple queries when using OOP

Tags: php, oop, optimization, mysqli, dry

When using OOP, how would you generally optimize classes like the following one for database performance while still following the DRY principle?

```
class AccountExampleClass
{
    private $_mysqli;

    // Current account ID
    private $_accountId;

    public function loginActions()
    {
        // Stuff to do on login
        // ...

        // Store the current time in last_activity and last_login, using 
        // two queries instead of one.
        $this->updateLastActivity();
        $this->_updateLastLogin();
    }

    // Run on every pageview
    public function updateLastActivity()
    {
        $this->_mysqli->query("UPDATE `accounts` SET `last_activity` = NOW()
            WHERE `id` = $this->_accountId LIMIT 1");
    }

    // Only run on login
    private function _updateLastLogin()
    {
        $this->_mysqli->query("UPDATE `accounts` SET `last_login` = NOW()
            WHERE `id` = $this->_accountId LIMIT 1");
    }
}
```

This is just a quick mockup to illustrate the problem. Both the last_activity and last_login fields has a method to update the database, but sometimes it's necessary to update both(as the loginActions method illustrates). By using multiple queries a lot of resources are wasted and the delay increases.

There are a bunch ways to do this that I can think of right now. Some of them are terrible and others are usable.

Here is a list:

- Make a specialized query manually and don't use the methods.

  - +Doesn't waste resources.
  - -Decreases the maintainability.
- Make a proxy-like class that can be told to optimize a group of queries before executing them.

  - +Creates optimized queries if told to.
  - +Can use methods in class.
  - -Have to specify what incoming queries it should optimize and tell it to execute the query afterwards.
  - -A small performance hit on application servers.
  - -Increased complexity as more external components are involved.
- Use objects to represent the current state of a row and save it all at once.

  - +Simplicity.
  - -A lot of unnecessary data is sent to the database.
  - -Wasted resources.
  - -Gets worse if data changes after the row is fetched.
- Use objects to represent the state of a row, but only save changed columns.
- ...

In situations like this, what would be the best balance between performance, complexity and maintainability?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the answer here is use an ORM layer that will take care of this for you, allowing you to update object properties and then persists those changes once you are done

> Invoking the persist method on an entity does NOT cause an immediate
>   SQL INSERT to be issued on the database. Doctrine applies a strategy
>   called “transactional write-behind”, which means that it will delay
>   most SQL commands until EntityManager#flush() is invoked which will
>   then issue all necessary SQL statements to synchronize your objects
>   with the database in the most efficient way and a single, short
>   transaction, taking care of maintaining referential integrity.

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/working-with-objects.html

Comment: This is the same problem: in the OP's example, who should call `flush`: `loginActions` or `updateLastActivity`?

Comment: the same problem as what? The point is that doctrine allows you to separate out the act of updating an object and finally updating the DB. As to when to call flush - well there are all kinds of sensible options including perhaps using __destruct()

Comment: This is what I meant by "proxy-like class". I think it might be the best solution considering DRY, even though there is a (small) performance hit and it needs a bit of extra code/complexity. If no one comes up with an awesome solution soon I'll mark this as the answer. I guess we have to choose between performance and maintainability as we can't have the best of both worlds. A good PHP ORM extension written in C would be awesome...Project idea? Hmm...

Answer (score 0):

Don't preemptively optimize, especially at the cost of adding complexity.  I think your idea about it adding a bunch of overhead is wrong.

If you really want to do this simply add a third method (something like updateBoth) or roll all these options into one method that accept a parameter based on the mode you want...

```
function updateTime($mode){
     if ($mode == "login){}
     else if ($mode == "activity"){}
     else {
       //update both
     }
}
```

Comment: Benchmark from testing: 96,2 % faster with a single somewhat heavy query using a php loop. I would not call this micro-optimization as it will be close to twice as fast with a single query if the query is heavy one. Micro-benchmarking shows that a simple page only creating a class and then looping the query inside the method if 92,1 % faster(and this is with the query cache in use). The "only one query"-example is also 18 % faster when benchmarking the whole LAMP stack with a single query on each http request. So if this is a waste of time to think about is a matter of query simplicity.

Comment: what are the run times though?  I'm guessing we are talking about microseconds.  No comments on my other thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

When a project like this starts, its common that many novice programmers code the SQL statements directly. More experienced programmers, use other, more complex, libraries like ORM, MVC, N-Tier layer.

You may want to start using ORM libraries, they support the "Make a proxy-like class", and "Use objects to represent the current state of a row" points you mention.

Object Relation Mapping (O.R.M.) libraries, sometimes support "Use objects to represent the current state of a row" approach, and, sometimes support "several rows or all rows", depending on what you want to do.

Some of them, allow to code SQL directly as a last resort, altought, common operations, insert, update, query, are handled by methods.

They are also helpful, if you need, to change the database server, or just change the identifier of a table or a field. Or, when you use several databases or several tables, that have the same structure / schema. Example: Sales-January, Sales-February.

These libraries, may be a little complex to understand, but, once you get used to them, they help you, handle more complex operations, like the one, you post.

Just my 2 cents.